# Jquery load JSON, update form fields

Tags: jquery, json, forms

I'm currently using the following to load some JSON data and then matching the JSON name to a form field name and updating the form value.

```
data: {'id': id},
      url: 'load.php',
      success: function(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            $('input[name="'+i+'"]').val(data[i]);
            }
        }
```

load.php returns the results for the specific ID as json formatted data.

This works and is updating my forms `input` fields without issue.

The issue I have is with select options and selecting the correct option and with checkboxes and having the correct state set.

Is there any way to loop through the JSON data and have it update each form field, either input, checkbox or select correctly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could decide your action on element `type`. `select` and `input` should work fine with `.val()`. For checkboxes you need `prop` to check them.

```
success: function(data) {
    for (var i in data) {
        var element = $('input[name="'+i+'"]');

        if( element.is("[type=checkbox]") ) {
            element.prop("checked", data[i]); // maybe adjust your select decision here
                                              // I don't know your JSON
        }
        else {
            element.val(data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Best solution is that - add another key in your json response. for example say - we have added fieldType

```
//sample json response
[{ 
 fieldType: 'checkbox',
 name: 'zyx',
 value: 12
}]
```

Js Code:

```js
success: function(data) {
 var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
 _.each(response, function(key, field, context){
   switch(field.fieldType){
    case 'select':
       $('select["name='+ field.name +'"]').val(field.value);
      break;
    default: //input type text
       $('["name='+ field.name +'"]').val(field.value);
      break;
      
   }
 });
}
```